# AH00534: apache2: Configuration error: No MPM loaded

Tags: apache2

Apache server has stopped and does not want to restart.

I have looked for several solutions and consulted several sources but no one seems to have a solution for this problem. Please do note that the MPM module currently enabled is `mpm_event`. I share the outputs received as a result of the diagnoses made:

*sudo systemctl status apache2*

```
× apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2022-11-23 09:37:35 UTC; 27min ago
       Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
    Process: 1927397 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 16ms

Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
AH00534: apache2: Configuration error: No MPM loaded.
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

*apache2ctl status*

```
lynx: Can't access startfile http://localhost/server-status 'www-browser -dump http://localhost:80/server-status' failed.
Maybe you need to install a package providing www-browser or you need to adjust the APACHE_LYNX variable in /etc/apache2/envvars
```

Apache version 2.4.52

Ubuntu 22.04

Is there a solution? If not, maybe Apache can be uninstalled and then installed once again?